# Principal component analysis (PCA) compute mean using python

Tags: python, numpy, face-recognition, mean, pca

I am a beginner to python and I am implementing Principal component analysis (PCA) using python, but I am having a problem computing the mean.
Here is my code:

```
import Image
import os
from PIL import Image
from numpy import *
import numpy as np


#import images
dirname = "C:\\Users\\Karim\\Downloads\\att_faces\\New folder"
X = [np.asarray(Image.open(os.path.join(dirname, fn))) for fn in os.listdir(dirname)]

#get number of images and dimentions
path, dirs, files = os.walk(dirname).next()
num_images = len(files)
image_file = "C:\\Users\\Karim\\Downloads\\att_faces\\New folder\\2.pgm"
img = Image.open(image_file)
width, height = img.size

print width
print height
print num_images

M = (X-mean(X.T,axis=1)).T # subtract the mean (along columns)
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'T'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`images -= np.mean(images, axis=0)`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `X.T` in your last line because `X` is a python list, not a `numpy.ndarray`. It isn't clear what you're trying to do here but if you wanted to combine all the image arrays into a single numpy array, you could convert `X = np.array(X)` before the last line.

Also, unless you specifically want to roll your own PCA implementation, you can do this much more easily with numpy by using `np.cov` (for covariance calculation) and `np.linalg.eig` (to compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the covariance matrix).

Comment: when I tried np.cov(X) I got this error:
ValueError: objects are not aligned

Comment: It's hard to diagnose this without seeing the code that creates `X`. Is it an ndarray? If so, what is its shape? My guess is that either `X` is not an ndarray or your image arrays are not all the same length. If the image arrays are not all the same length, then you will have a different problem trying to compute the covariance (with  or without numpy).

Comment: @user2229953 It seems that `X` is a list of `np.arrays` generated from `PIL` images.  Probably the analysis should be done on each element of `X`, not on `np.asarray(X)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916837/how-to-get-the-1st-principal-component-by-pca-using-python